# C++ Pointer assignment not working (off by 34 bytes)

Tags: c++, pointers

In a large, single threaded, C++ application (compiled with GCC 4.4.7 20120313), the simple pointer assignment does not equal the original pointer value:

```
class DvComVectorStreamBase : virtual public std::ios
{
    // some stuff here
};

class DvComVectorOStream : public DvComVectorStreamBase, public std::ostream
{
public:
    DvComVectorOStream(int which = std::ios::out, size_t capacity = 0) :
        DvComVectorStreamBase(which, capacity)
    {}
};


class Formatter : public aStandAloneClass
{
    // cruft removed

protected:
    void initFunction();

    ostream*                 mpStream;
    DvComVectorOStream*      mpVectorOStream;
}

Formatter:initFunction()
{
    printf("mpStream %p mpVectorOStream %p\n", (void *)mpStream, (void *)mpVectorOStream);
    if (mpVectorOStream == 0)
        mpVectorOStream = new DvComVectorOStream(ios::out, 32768);
    else
        mpVectorOStream->clear();

    printf("mpStream %p mpVectorOStream %p\n", (void *)mpStream, (void *)mpVectorOStream);
    mpStream = mpVectorOStream;
    printf("mpStream %p mpVectorOStream %p\n", (void *)mpStream, (void *)mpVectorOStream);
}
```

**Output**

```
mpStream (nil) mpVectorOStream (nil)
mpStream (nil) mpVectorOStream 0x90ccc98
mpStream 0x90ccccc mpVectorOStream 0x90ccc98
```

Trying to recreate the problem in a trivial test case works fine.

Should not mpStream and mpVectorOStream have identical values after assignment?

ie. If both pointers are pointing to the same object, then each pointer should contain the same value, no?  (isn't that the whole point of the assignment operator?)

Comment: nil? what compiler is that?

Comment: looks like clang to me.

Comment: You're probably doing multiple inheritance, in which case the base class pointer is often different from the derived class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a class has multiple base classes, only the first one starts at the same address as the subclass, so when you convert a subclass pointer to a base class pointer, the value of the pointer may change to point to the base class instance within the subclass instance.

Similarly, when you convert a base class pointer to a subclass pointer, the value may need to change to point to the containing subclass

Similar adjustments will occur even for single inheritance, when the derived class has a v-table and the base class doesn't.